# Understanding Multiple Logistic Regression Interactions

Tags: regression, logistic

I ran a logistic regression with categorical variables.  The estimates and odds ratios are:
Marital_Status- Estimate: .6605  Odds Ratio: 3.747
Professional Suffix: .5342   Odds Ratio: 2.911

I understand that the odds ratio says :
"The odds of the dependent variable happening is 3.747 times higher if someone is married than if someone is single"
and 
"The odds of the dependent variable happening is 2.911 times higher if someone has a professional suffix than if they don't"

Question: Is there a way to say "If someone is married AND they have a professional suffix then they odds of the dependent variable happening will be ___? Would it be Y(1)= intercept + .6605O + .5342? 
Or is that unnecessary to do?  Should results only be looked at with holding all other independent variables constant?

Comment: Odds ratio means one's odds vs another's odds. In your example, the ratio of odds of married vs not married is 3.747. In your question, one person is married and has a professional suffix. Which one is another person?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question but for example i guess I'd wonder what is the odds of married and has a professional suffix vs not married with no professional suffix.

Comment: Yes, your answer is clear. Your another person is not married with no professional suffix. Could you post more information on your model fitting? Given the estimate of the  that coefficient being 0.6605, the odds ratio should be $\exp(0.6605) = 1.9358$. where that 3.747 comes from? Same question for 2.911. Any interaction and/or other variables in the model?

Comment: There are a total of 14 variables in the model.  I ran a correlation matrix to see if there were any correlations between variables and there didn't seem to be any

Comment: To help with the understanding here is the cross tab for both variables.   Marital Status 0 - Donor 0 - 29264  
Marital Status 0 - Donor 1 - 9137
Marital Status 1 - Donor 0 - 9631
Marital Status 1 - Donor 0 - 13325

Prof Suffix 0 - Donor 0 - 38382  
Prof Suffix 0 - Donor 1 - 21143
Prof Suffix 1 - Donor 0 - 513
Prof Suffix 1 - Donor 0 - 1319

Doing the odds ratio calculations by had I observed: Marital Status - 4.43 and Prof Suffix - 4.67

Comment: The (14 or more than 14) estimate of the logistic regression coefficients are needed. Also the coding methods is needed also. Correlation is not big issue given your model is fit already.

Answer (score 1):

The interpretation you suggest is in fact the one that is expected. Interaction effects and the effects of the constituent predictors need to be interpreted jointly, and one computes marginal effects for this.

See e.g. Buis M. 2010. "Stata tip 87: Interpretation of interactions in nonlinear
models" *The Stata Journal*, 10(2) or [the equivalent in R](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/margins/vignettes/Introduction.html).

You might also want to read:
Brambor, T., Clark, W. R., and Golder, M. (2006). Understanding interaction models: Improving empirical analyses. *Political Analysis*, 14(1):63–82.

Comment: +1 Also worth a read: Keele, L., & Stevenson, R. T. (2017). [Causal Interaction and Effect Modification: Same Model, Different Concepts](https://files.osf.io/v1/resources/azx52/providers/osfstorage/58a264bf594d9001f1ed7a92).

Answer (score -1):

If you created a derived binary variable to flag that condition vs the other, you could retrain the model after removing the original variables and get your answer. I do not think you can arrive at the answer you want without doing so.